# What to do when pyinstaller does not seem to be working?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a client.py that I want to turn into a .exe as it would mean they can be executed on computers that do not have python. While using pyinstaller, I opened cmd and typed 'pyinstaller client.py'. When doing this I waited a few mins but discovered it had not worked and the disc folder did not have the .exe. Does anyone know what went wrong?

Comment: 'executed on computers that do not have python' --- there's other ways than exe, portable python is a choice.

Comment: Can you paste the output of your command in your question ?